# Mobile Redirect Loop

Tags: php, wordpress, mobile

I want mobile users to be redirected to a specific page on my WP site. I am trying to use this script, but it's causing an infinite loop. Can the mobile page be on the same domain or do I have to create a sub-domain for the mobile page?

Thanks!

```
function is_mobile(){
    $regex_match="/(nokia|iphone|android|motorola|^mot\-|softbank|foma|docomo|kddi|up\.browser|up\.link|";
    $regex_match.="htc|dopod|blazer|netfront|helio|hos in|huawei|novarra|CoolPad|webos|techfaith|palmsour ce|";
    $regex_match.="blackberry|alcatel|amoi|ktouch|nexi an|samsung|^sam\-|s[cg]h|^lge|ericsson|philips|sagem|wellcom|bunjalloo|ma ui|";  
    $regex_match.="symbian|smartphone|midp|wap|phone|w indows ce|iemobile|^spice|^bird|^zte\-|longcos|pantech|gionee|^sie\-|portalmmm|";
    $regex_match.="jig\s browser|hiptop|^ucweb|^benq|haier|^lct|opera\s*mob i|opera\*mini|320x320|240x320|176x220";
    $regex_match.=")/i";    

    return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_WAP_PROFILE']) or isset($_SERVER['HTTP_PROFILE']) or preg_match($regex_match, strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']));
}

switch($_GET['mode'])
{
case 'mobile':
    $mode = "mobile";
    break;
case 'desktop':
    $mode = "desktop";
    break;
default:
    $mode = is_mobile() ? "mobile" : "desktop";
    break;
}

if ($mode == "mobile")
{
    header ("Location: http://example.com/mobile");
    return;
```

Comment: If you are using this on every page, you would have to also add something to check if the url is under `/mobile` and not redirect if it is.

Comment: @this_guy fyi, you may consider using responsive design rather than a mobile website. it's only a suggestion, but it will mean your site will work on any device / screen size

Comment: That's what I usually do, but a client requested it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a check before issuing the location header that you're not currently on a mobile page (e.g. by checking `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`or via some variable that you set only on mobile page), or don't include this redirect script when you're on a mobile page.

Comment: Something so simple was giving me a headache all day. Thanks!